# jQuery - Add class based on url and without url

Tags: jquery, class, url

[Update code again]
I have the following code:

```
var header_url = window.location.href;
if(/index/.test(header_url)||/home/.test(header_url)){
    $('#home').addClass('select');
} else if(/about/.test(header_url)) {
    $('#about').addClass('select');
} else if(/contact/.test(header_url)) {
    $('#contact').addClass('select');
}
```

The code is work, when I click them:

```
http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/about.html
http://example.com/contact.html
```

But if I want to add another page, set it as default main page without url, like this:

```
http://example.com
```

I try to add code but it doesn't work:

```
else if(/.test(header_url)) {
        $('#default').addClass('select');
    }
```

Can anybody help please? thx!

Comment: Use `default` case in `switch`

Comment: @Tushar Sorry I posted the wrong code, can you please check again?

Comment: Then add an `else` at the end and use it for `default` case

Comment: yes, you will use else on behalf default.

Comment: fixed it, big thx for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created proper expression for last condition. Try below code

```js
var header_url = 'http://example.com';
//var header_url = 'http://example.com/index.html';
//var header_url = 'http://example.com/about.html';
//var header_url =  'http://example.com/contact.html';
if(/index/.test(header_url)||/home/.test(header_url)){
    console.log('index');
} else if(/about/.test(header_url)) {
    console.log('about');
} else if(/contact/.test(header_url)) {
    console.log('contact');
} else if(/\//.test(header_url)) {
   console.log('nothing');
}
```

Check this fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/k63f3a33/1/

Answer (score 1):

you have used default in switch case like

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
case '/index':
$('#home').addClass('select');
break;
case '/about':
$('#about').addClass('select');
break;
case '/contact':
$('#contact').addClass('select');
break;
default:
 $('#default').addClass('select');
break;
}
```

try this.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code, can you please check again? thx!